# Place cursor and select with the mouse in command-line interpreters?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, terminal, command-line-interface

Is there a CLI (command-line interpreter) that manages, for the current new command line, to place the cursor and select text with the mouse, and replace the selected text by what the user types or pasts?

I don't know any which support those extremely basic features (I'm mostly used to OS X's Terminal).

Do you know any good reason which explain why those features are not available by default on most CLI? Why it's not standard?

I'm interested in answers for all platforms.

**Disclaimer:** *I know this question can be down-voted but it talks about "software tools commonly used by programmers", so it's not off-topic [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).*

Comment: Are you asking for something like searching through past history of commands typed and run it in the present? If it's not, let us know more on the requirement

Comment: No, it's more to have text-editor like features in a CLI (for the current/new command). Like place cursor with mouse, select with mouse, copy and paste, replace selected text, etc.

Comment: X allow you to select text with your primary button, which is automatically stored in the clipboard, and pasted with the middle button.  The pasted text will appear at the cursor position.  Now moving the cursor is not possible, command line is sequential, you can't move back to type new commands.  This is a feature of X, and not of the terminal per say.  I keep an editor window close by if I need to edit past commands using more "sophisticated" methods.

Comment: Or you could use vi commands in bash (and Emacs if I remember correctly, I never used that).

Comment: I know about that.

Answer (score 1):

I think that most of CLI (readline, linenoise, nodejs shell, etc.) use only the keyboard to provide text insertion or erasure.

The mouse inesrtion and selection features are not provided by the CLI library, but the window-manager. When you paste text using the mouse, this text is just put into the terminal.

I never heard about a CLI library which would catch the mouse events to provide such a behavior. Maybe because it would become a text editor and no more a CLI...